What happen if CDF or survival of bivariate distribution is differentiated with one component only?
Hello brilliant people,
I have some questions regarding joint probability distribution. Let say I have a joint density $f(x,t)$. A joint CDF is computed as follows,
$$ F(x,t)=P(X<x,T<t)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\int_{-\infty}^{t}f(u,v) dvdu$$
$$ =\int_{-\infty}^{x}\int_{-\infty}^{t}f(v|u)\cdot f_X(u) dvdu$$
$$ =\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_X(u)\int_{-\infty}^{t}f(v|u) dvdu$$
$$ =\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_X(u)\cdot F(t|X=u) du.$$
If I want to get the rate of change of the CDF with respect to $t$, I can derive it as follows,
$$ \frac{\partial F(x,t)}{\partial t}=\frac{P(X<x,t-\Delta h<T<t)}{\Delta h}=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\int_{t-\Delta h}^{t}f(u,v) dvdu$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_X(u)\cdot \left[ \frac{F(t|X=u)-F(t-\Delta h|X=u)}{\Delta h} \right] du$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_X(u)\cdot f(t|X=u)du$$
Meanwhile, the survival of the joint probability is written similarly as below,
$$ S(x,t)=P(X>x,T>t)=\int_{x}^{\infty}f_X(u)\cdot S(t|X=u) du.$$
And when we compute the rate change of the survival with respect to $t$, I derived it as follows,
$$ \frac{\partial S(x,t)}{\partial t}=\frac{P(X>x,t<T<t+\Delta h)}{\Delta h}=\int_{x}^{\infty}\int_{t}^{t+\Delta h}f(u,v) dvdu$$
$$=\int_{x}^{\infty}f_X(u)\cdot \left[ \frac{F(t+\Delta h|X=u)-F(t|X=u)}{\Delta h} \right] du$$
$$=\int_{x}^{\infty}f_X(u)\cdot f(t|X=u)du.$$
Here, I got similar sign for both rate of change. But shouldn't we get different sign because for one variable case, the rate of change for CDF and survival should be different. I.E: $F'(y)=f(y)$ while $S'(y)=-f(y)$.
Which part am I missing here?
Thank you in advance.

You have the CDF in the [ ]brackets in the wrong order on the second last line.  The survival function is non-increasing, and $F(T=t+\Delta h\mid X=u)\geq F(T=t\mid X=u)$, so you need to subtract the LHS from the RHS.

Yes, they will have different signs.  The first is the derivative of a non-decreasing function (a CDF) while the second is the derivative of a non-increasing function (a survival function). 
$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial F(T=t\mid X=u)}{\partial t}&=\lim\limits_{\Delta h\searrow 0}\dfrac{F(T=t\mid X=u)-F(T=t-\Delta h\mid X=u)}{\Delta h} \\[2ex]&= f_{T}(t\mid X=u)\\[4ex]\dfrac{\partial S(T=t\mid X=u)}{\partial t}&=\lim\limits_{\Delta h\searrow 0}\dfrac{S(T=t+\Delta h\mid X=u)-S(T=t\mid X=u)}{\Delta h}\\[2ex] &=\lim\limits_{\Delta h\searrow 0}\dfrac{1-F(T=t+\Delta h\mid X=u)-1+F(T=t\mid X=u)}{\Delta h}\\[2ex]&=\lim\limits_{\Delta h\searrow 0}\dfrac{F(T=t\mid X=u)-F(T=t+\Delta h\mid X=u)}{\Delta h} \\[2ex]&= {-}f_{T}(t\mid X=u)\end{align}$$

Okay now I see it. What a silly mistake. Thanks a lot @Graham Kemp
